# Dynamic pivot unknown number of rows - Sql View

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm using SQL to create a database VIEW from the table below.

```
ItemCode                |BcdName           |BcdCode      |
------------------------|------------------|-------------|
03616006.ERA            |EAS               |00060914ER   |
03616006.ERA            |EAN               |8053379025831|
02660402.ERA            |EAS               |00060936ER   |
02660402.ERA            |EAN               |8053379026227|
02660402.ERA            |EANBULK           |00060936ET   |
```

I need to pivot the BcdName (for an unknown number of columns) and get the following result:

```
ItemCode                |EAN               |EAS          |EANBULK      |
------------------------|------------------|-------------|-------------|
03616006.ERA            |8053379025831     |00060914ER   |             |
02660402.ERA            |8053379026227     |00060936ER   |00060936ET   |
```

The solution found here: [dynamic pivot issue in sql server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657365/dynamic-pivot-issue-in-sql-server-2012) is not working on a table View.

Comment: You can not use DYNAMIC SQL in a view.  Does it really need to be dynamic?  Can you settle on a defined set of columns?

Comment: I would prefer to work on a dynamic set of values. can I get to the desired result by limiting the number of columns to 5 (EAN, EAS, EANBULK,EASBULK, [EMPTY])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to settle for defined columns with a "**Warning/Undefined**" column

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From  (Select ItemCode
              ,Item     = case when [BcdName] in ('EAN','EAS','EANBULK','EASBULK') then BcdName else 'Empty' end
              ,Value    = [BcdCode]
          From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ([EAN],[EAS],[EANBULK],[EASBULK],[EMPTY]) ) Pvt
```

**Returns**

```
ItemCode        EAN             EAS         EANBULK     EASBULK EMPTY
02660402.ERA    8053379026227   00060936ER  00060936ET  NULL    SomeValue
03616006.ERA    8053379025831   00060914ER  NULL        NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Super neat solution! Thanks!

Comment: @MirkoNardi Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @John's comment here.

A view based on a pivot statement would have to contain the specific "pivot values" hard-coded into it, meaning you'd have to know them at the time you created the view. As per the referenced answer (one of hundreds, I'm sure), the only way to do "on the fly" pivot column selection is with dynamic SQL, and `CREATE VIEW` statements cannot contain dynamic SQL.

Comment: In fact I've found hundreds of examples using dynamic sql. Strange there's no a way around this....

Comment: Agreed. I don't know about views, but it's such a common problem you'd think MS would come up with something to help out. They wired in temporal tables, after all...